# linq query for returning single row

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

For any transaction happening a row is inserted into my table.

i have table(Transactions)like following

ID----------Amount

1------------150.00

2-----------    246.00

3-----------    100.00

4-----------    201.00

If the above transaction is happening with multiple tender types(cash,creditcard etc),for each tender type a row is inserted into another table.

This new table(Tender) looks like following

ID----  TenderType----- TransactionId

1-----------    10 ----        1

2------------   20----         2

3-------------10-----2

The above tells that,the 1st Transaction(from Transactions table,amount 150.00) happened with only one tender type(10).So one one row in Tender table.

The 2nd transaction(amount 246.00) happened with two tender types(10 and 20).So two rows in Tender table.

Now i want the output as

Amount------ TenderType

150.00 ------ 10

246.66-------10/20

Now i am writing a linq query in c# and it is returning two rows if there are multiple rows in Tender table for each Amount in Transaction table.

My query look like following:

```
(from T in context.Transactions
join TT in context.TenderType on T.ID equals TT.TransactionId
select new myModel
{
    Amount = T.Amount,
    TenderType = TT.TenderType
}).ToList();
```

For this query my output looks like this:

Amount------ TenderType

150.00 ------ 10

246.66-------10

246.66-------20

But my output should be like this :

Amount------ TenderType

150.00 ------ 10

246.66-------10/20

How to modify my query to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 (from T in context.Transactions
  select new myModel
 {
    Amount = T.Amount,
    TenderType = context.TenderType.Where(x=>x.TransactionId==T.ID).Select(x=>x.TenderType).FirstOrDefault()
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: here my TenderType is string and cannot implicity convert type of my database model to string

Comment: as this has FirstOrDefault(),it returns the first value from Tender table and just gives only one in case of 2 rows in Tender table for each transaction

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can have a [one to many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) association from Transaction to Tender.

```
public class Transaction {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public double Amount { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Tender> Tenders { get; set; }
}

from T in context.Transactions
select new {
  Amount = T.Amount,
  TenderTypes = T.Tenders.Select(t => t.TenderType)
}
```

Comment: Assigning to TenderTypes ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What is "TenderTypes" in the above query

Comment: TenderTypes is an IEnumerable<String>.  So each row returned is a double Amount, IEnumberable<String> TenderTypes.  (Assuming that Tender.TenderType is a string as you suggest)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var result= (from T in context.Transactions
             join TT in context.TenderType
             on T.ID equals TT.TranscationID into g
             select new 
             {
                Amount = t.Amount,
                TenderType = String.Join("/",g.Select(x => x.TenderTypeID))
             }).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TenderType));
```